# Buffered channel to accumulate data up to a limit

Tags: go, buffer, channel

My application consumes data from Kinesis, process it and forwards it to another microservice. In order to reduce the number of requests to the last, I'm trying to implement a queue of objects with a policy of forwarding its items once a defined queue length is reached or once a timeout is reached (to avoid stuck items for a long time).

So far I've found a good example to implement the timeout [here](https://www.loxodrome.io/post/set-timeout-interval-go/), but I'm struggling with the queue of objects. I've read a lot about buffered channels, however I'm not sure if they are the way to go.

According to [this reference](https://medium.com/capital-one-developers/buffered-channels-in-go-what-are-they-good-for-43703871828), a buffered channel can be used to *limit the amount of work that is queued up, preventing your services from falling behind and becoming overwhelmed*. However, it seems that what I need is not limit the amount of work, but simply accumulate work (my Kinesis stream data) to be dealt in batches.

So for my queue of objects, would it be enough a slice and a go routine checking its length, so the data would be forwarded once it reached a certain size? Or there are good reasons to use a buffered channel?

Comment: There's no functional difference between an array and a channel for this. They're both a fixed/maximum-length collection of things.

Comment: If you meant slice, when you said array, then your structure can grow unbounded (until you run out of memory). If you intend to drain your queue when it reaches a certain size, then this probably isn't necessary either.  So then you're back to considering the equivalent array vs channel question. In short: Pick the one that's easiest for you to use.

Comment: Actually I meant slice. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If there is no concurrency involved, the locking semantics that happen behind the scenes for a channel send/receive represent unnecessary overhead for a simple queue data structure. Probably negligible overhead in the grand scheme but something to keep in mind.

Comment: Not sure what your trying to do, perhaps your wording is being misunderstood.  Have you considered batching the work.  Here's a quick example
https://goplay.space/#ajd1ffBlz9m